# Running external application from RDP session using Process

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

I have 2 apps. One of which is installed on a client computer and actually does something (adds data to a local quickbooks company file) and the other is designed to be run from a remote computer executed via RDP. I am trying to figure out exactly how to code it in C# so when the app on the remote computer is started, it starts the app on the local machine (using \tsclient) without actually "running" the app on the remote computer. I want the app being called to do all of its work on the local machine as thats where the data is at, however whenever I run it currently, it executes as if I am trying to run the client app on the remote computer (brings up the window on the remote computer, tries to process on the remote computer).

Is there any way to do this?

Currently the code for the simple app on the remote machine that tries to call the client-side app is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process testInterface = new Process();
    testInterface.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\tsclient\C\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\qbinterface\qbinterface\bin\Debug\interface.exe";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you run the Process to be started on the machine where the process runs which tries to start the other process.

For your purpose, you need an application running on the other computer (tsclient) which listens for commands from the first machine (RDP server), and then executes them. Learn more on how two computers can communicate with each other, how to exchange data between them etc. ( .Net remoting, WCF, SOAP, Json and so on may be involved).